# Flutter Modules, importación en Xcode - iOS

Tags: flutter, xcode

actualmente tengo la necesidad de crear un módulo de flutter e importarlo a un proyecto existente (android y iOS) para android no hay tema alguno, pero en iOS/xcode me he encontrado con el siguiente problema:
Se ha seguido la documentación oficial
Se importó el código de manera satisfactoria
Las pruebas en simulador/dispositivo son satisfactorias
Pero al momento de desconectar el dispositivo y correr la aplicación, ésta truena cuando quiero invocar el módulo que hice en flutter.
Sucede lo mismo cuando creo el IPA y lo subo a un ambiente de pruebas en firebase app distribution (es el ambiente que usamos en la empresa para probar las aplicaciones en ambiente de desarrollo y pruebas de QA)

Investigando un poco, al parecer esto sucede porque al momento de desplegar el IPA o correr la aplicación sin tenerla compilando en xcode, lo que intenta llamar mi aplicación es la versión de release del módulo, en lugar de la versión de debug (ambas versiones, release y debug se generan y agregan correctamente a la aplicación).

Alguien sabe si es posible llamar la versión de debug una vez generado el IPA? o creen que el problema pudiera ser otro?

Espero alguien me pudiera orientar un poco mejor.

De antemano muchas gracias